What causes mavproxy 'link 1 down' error?
When I try to connect as shown in the image, there is a waiting time of about 3 seconds and then it gives a link 1 down error. How can I solve it? I'm trying to establish its relationship with qground control. I am using Ubuntu 18_04.
MAVProxy git:(master) mavproxy.py --master udp:0.0.0.0:14550 --out udp:192.168.1.222:14560
Connect udp:0.0.0.0:14550 source_system=255
Log Directory:
Telemetry log: mav.tlog
Waiting for heartbeat from 0.0.0.0:14550
MAV> link 1 down
(https://i.sstatic.net/KPLP0nxG.png)
